# How to run all files in folder seeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have folder **db/seeds**, which include about 20 files with default values for project.

Provide me correct setting for running command rake db:seed for load all this files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create one file at `lib/tasks/`. give name `main_seed_file.rake` to the new file. paste below code into `main_seed_file.rake`.

```
 desc "Run all files in db/seeds directory"
 namespace :db do
   task seeds: :environment do
     Dir[File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds', '*.rb')].each do |filename|
       puts "seeding - #{filename}"
       load(filename)
     end
   end
 end
```

Now execute this `rake db:seeds`

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you this is working like a charm! it took me a while to find something like this, everything focussed on executing one task only, very helpful

Comment: @d1jhoni1b: My pleasure!